# Как добавить свойство вложенного элемента стилизуемому

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю карточную игру на память. У меня будут создаваться карточки, а в них случайно вкладываться картинки, у каждой карты есть пара которая случайно будет расположена на сетке.

В качестве карты я использую стилизованный чек-бокс, в котором содержится border и image. Что бы иметь возможность задавать различные картинки стилизованному чек-боксу мне нужно добавить на него свойство Source. Можете описать как это можно сделать? Код карточки ниже.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"
       x:Key="CardSelectionTheme">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Border CornerRadius="15"
                            BorderBrush="#4169e1"
                            BorderThickness="3"
                            Background="#1e90ff"
                            x:Name="OneDouble">
                        <Border.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="15"
                                   RadiusY="15"
                                   Rect="0 0 120 190"/>
                        </Border.Clip>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Margin="7"
                                   Height="500"
                                   Source="/Images/zakat.png">
                            </Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="OneDouble" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Comment: Зачем тут чекбокс? Вы очень сильно усложняете себе задачу, очень! Сделайте VM класс одной карты, пусть там будет тип и название, дальше сгенерируйте коллекцию этих карт, чтоб они там были в случайном порядке (по 2 карты каждого типа), затем в View сделайте `ItemsControl`, который будет привязан к коллекции и разместит карты при помощи `WrapPanel`, далее сделайте вид для одной карты, пусть это будет кнопка (может `ToggleButton`), где будет картинка и ее название (если надо), анимация переворота, ну и др. мелочи. По команде кнопки вы сохраняете 2 последних кликнутых карты и сверяете, все...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Звучит действительно здорово. Но я не уверен что смогу это сделать. У меня 3 дня на разработку осталось. Хотел бы я вас попросить поподробней об этом рассказать, но вряд ли вам захочется тратить на это время. В любом случае спасибо за полезную информацию.